# Half of Dirac Delta within spectral integration

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fourier-transform, dirac-delta-distributions

I was taking a course in Quantum Information along this last semester, and apart from some mathematical details it all made sense to me. One of these mathematical tricks that I haven't been able to quite understand is the following.

During some microscopic derivations using Nakajima-Zwansig we had to compute an integral of the form

$$I=\int\limits_0^{+\infty}\int\limits_0^{+\infty}\frac{ds\,d\Omega}{2\pi}\,e^{is(\omega-\Omega)}f(\Omega),$$

And the argument we used to do so was that the first term is almost a Dirac delta,

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{ds}{2\pi}\,e^{is(\omega-\Omega)}=\delta(\omega-\Omega),$$
except it isn't. We would then write

$$\int\limits_0^{+\infty}\frac{ds}{2\pi}\,e^{is(\omega-\Omega)}=\frac{1}{2}\delta(\omega-\Omega)-\frac{i}{2}P\left(\frac{1}{\omega-\Omega}\right),$$
where $P$ is the Cauchy principal value.

The hand-waviness to come was that this principal value would do nothing but renormize $\omega$, resulting in something akin to a Lamb shift. We would then neglect this term and write

$$I=\frac{1}{2}f(\omega),$$
with this $\omega$ being slightly different from the one we started with.

This makes no sense to me. First of all, from the little I know about principal values, the term on the right should simply zero out and then we would simply get the Dirac delta. What am I missing here?

Comment: Hint: Use the [Sokhotski–Plemelj formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokhotski%E2%80%93Plemelj_theorem) together with the Fourier transform of the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).